# How to cancel a step from Spring batch besides returning null from reader

Tags: spring-batch, cancellation

Is there a way to cancel a step but not the job from Spring batch? I thought when you used a "org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SkipLimitStepFactoryBean" and the property "fatalExceptionClasses", when the fatal exception happened, the step was cancelled but not the entire job. I dont understand why if this property is inside a step it cancels the entire job.

I know I can return null from a reader. Other way?

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to complete the step?

Comment: No, cancel its execution and execute the next step

Comment: can't you just configure the flow accordingly? see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134634/spring-batch-java-config-skip-step-when-exception-and-go-to-next-steps/39143725#39143725